# Is there any way to get my own image base without calling any WinAPI functions, such as GetModuleHandle?

Tags: windows, pe, executable, exe

Is there any way to get the image base of an `.exe` without calling WinAPI functions (i.e. imported functions) so that it can't be easily viewed in a disassembler/debugger?

I've been thinking of declaring a global variable anywhere in code and reading its address in a loop backwards until e.g.`MZ` is found (obviously checking for `NULL` in the meantime). However, there may be a section which isn't readable, a string in `.rdata` which contains the `MZ` characters or some value (especially a function address or generally pointers) that contains the `MZ` bytes (`0x4D`, `0x5A`) (and probably a few more "situations").

Have you any idea how to achieve that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways of doing that

#### Scanning memory from EIP

You could easily get the `EIP` of your own code without calling any APIs. There are a few ways to achieve that using inline assembly, but the most common one is to include the following two instructions:

```
call $+5
pop eax
```

This works because `call` will push the next address (where `pop eax` is onto the stack) and then execute the instruction right after it (again, our `pop eax`). When `pop eax` is executed, it'll pop the address just pushed by `call $+5` into a register.

After you got your `EIP` value you can easily scan backwards as you thought of doing, but this time starting at a position a lot closer to your image base.

Keeping in mind image bases are aligned to page boundaries, you can scan in `PAGE_SIZE` (4096 bytes) intervals.

#### Reading loaded modules from PEB

The [Process Environment Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) (also [here](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb/)) structure is accessible using a designated segment register (`fs` on 32 bit systems and `gs` on 64 bit systems) which stores the address of the [Thread Information Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) from which the PEB is reachable. Although most of the PEB is undocumented, in it is a lot of data relating to the operational aspects of the currently running process.

One such piece of information is the `ImageBaseAddress`, an undocumented (but consistent) field that holds the process's image base. If you're interested in the `.exe`'s image base (opposed to a loaded DLLs image base), this will do.

If you want something more reliable you could use the `Ldr` member, which points to a [`PEB_LDR_DATA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/ns-winternl-_peb_ldr_data) structure which points to a linked list of [`LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/ns-winternl-_peb_ldr_data)s, which lists all loaded modules, their addresses and a lot of other information about each loaded module. Your executable's image base is the `DllBase` field.

Comment: `PEB.ImageBaseAddress` will be easier than walking the Ldr structures.

Comment: @Nirlzr Thank you very much, that's a great idea! 
 I can't however understand why I can read the `eip` in `0x1000` intervals. If you meant something like: `while(*(WORD*)eip != 'ZM') (DWORD)eip -= PAGE_SIZE;`, then what if the image base actually was `0x400000` and the `eip` was, say, `0x400ABC`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @joshpoley Cool. I thought there must be something like that but couldn't find it when skimming for it. I'll add that!

Comment: @Jason You can easily align the address to a 4k boundary by performing `eip & ~(4096-1)`

Comment: @Nirlzr Alright, I've already seen this technique with virtual addresses, just misunderstood you.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Visual C++, you can use the special symbol `__ImageBase` which points to image base of the current module. For example, here's code from VS2010 CRT source (`pesect.c`):

```
BOOL __cdecl _IsNonwritableInCurrentImage(
    PBYTE pTarget
    )
{
    PBYTE                 pImageBase;
    DWORD_PTR             rvaTarget;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSection;

    pImageBase = (PBYTE)&__ImageBase;

    __try {
        //
        // Make sure __ImageBase does address a PE image.  This is likely an
        // unnecessary check, since we should be running from a normal image,
        // but it is fast, this routine is rarely called, and the normal call
        // is for security purposes.  If we don't have a PE image, return
        // failure.
        //
        if (!_ValidateImageBase(pImageBase))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        //
        // Convert the targetaddress to a Relative Virtual Address (RVA) within
        // the image, and find the corresponding PE section.  Return failure if
        // the target address is not found within the current image.
        //
        rvaTarget = pTarget - pImageBase;
        pSection = _FindPESection(pImageBase, rvaTarget);
        if (pSection == NULL)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        //
        // Check the section characteristics to see if the target address is
        // located within a writable section, returning a failure if yes.
        //
        return (pSection->Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE) == 0;
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
    {
        //
        // Just return failure if the PE image is corrupted in any way that
        // triggers an AV.
        //
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

At the top of the file there is code declaring this variable as `extern`:

```
#if defined (_WIN64) && defined (_M_IA64)
#pragma section(".base", long, read)
__declspec(allocate(".base"))
extern IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#else  /* defined (_WIN64) && defined (_M_IA64) */
extern IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#endif  /* defined (_WIN64) && defined (_M_IA64) */
```

So it may be that the key is the `.base` section and not the variable name by itself.

Comment: +1 Cool! I couldn't find any official documentation, the closest thing was this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483/ Too bad it's Visual C specific!

Answer (score 4):

To get your own image base in 32-bit code, you can do this:

```
mov eax, fs:[30h]
mov eax, [eax+8]
```

which you can obviously obfuscate in multiple ways, such as by moving fs: into ds: temporarily, calculating "30h" and "8" by multiplying, etc.

64-bit code is gs:[60h] and +10h instead.

Comment: Might wanna mention that this is effectively the [PEB](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/peb/)/[TEB](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/structs/teb/) method discussed in the accepted answer.

Comment: Definitely a more to-the-point and a practical take on that, though! +1